# IBM Bluemix Watson visual recognition authorization issue

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

under my IBM Bluemix account, I have registered a Watson Visual Recognition service.
My intention is to call the service from Bizagi BPMS as REST service.
Bizagi brings an "unauthorized" error.

The URL for the REST Service is
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition-beta/api/v2/classify

The Service URL is
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition-beta/api/?username=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&password=yyyyyyyyyyy 
(x and y are the credentials from the service instance in Bluemix.
When entering the Service URL directly into the browser, I can enter the authentication credentials in a popup window, but the response is 
"Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: / "

Answer (score 3):

The service uses Basic Authorization so you need to send the `username` and `password` Base64 encoded.

On the other hand, the Visual Recognition service requires you to send the image you want to recognize. If you use a browser you need to point to a GET call. Open a browser using this url: https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition-beta/api/v2/classifiers?version=2015-12-02

That should return the list of classifiers.

**Example Output:**

```
{
  "classifiers": [
    {
      "classifier_id": "nightvsday_11138698",
      "name": "night vs day"
    },
    {
      "classifier_id": "tiger_458617357",
      "name": "tiger"
    },
    {
      "classifier_id": "Black",
      "name": "Black"
    },
    {
      "classifier_id": "Blue",
      "name": "Blue"
    }
 ]
}
```

For more examples look at the [Visual Recognition API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v2/?curl#classify_an_image).